# Obtaining information of all habitats within an area (raster overlapping with polygon) using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a raster TIFF containing a habitat map. The raster, with resolution of 10m x 10m, indicates a different code for each pixel (say code 1 = woodland, 2 = grassland, 3 = urban area.
I've got another vector files containing multiple polygons indicating several demarcated area.

For each polygon I want the information of which percentage of woodland, grassland, urban area etc. i.e. different type of habitat according to the raster TIFF.

I am using QGIS 3.22. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Zonal Histogram. Output will contain one column with pixel count for each raster value
2. Multiple Field Calculators or one Refactor fields to create new columns with percentages for each class.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The answer helps me a lot.
OTOL for Refactor Fields do we have an option to import an excel or CSV file that contains Field Mapping attributes including Source Expression, Name, Type, Length. So that we don't need to input them manually?

Comment: Use load fields from to load all existing fields from Zonal Histogram. I dont think there's a way of loading expression to calculate the percentages. Do you have many codes/values?

Comment: Thanks for the information! But how exactly can I run the python script to the layer of polygon with habitat data imported?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I found another way that I copied the data of attribute table of demarcated area containing informations of habitat and render the data in excel. Then I put the data back to QGIS and it works!